# axios returns 500 while postman returns 200

Tags: reactjs, axios, proxy

I am trying to call an API using axios but the problem is that it keeps returning `500` while postman is returning `200`.

I've tried using `fetch` too but the result didn't change.
Here's my code and I hope you can help me out on this one.
and also I'm using a proxy in my `package.json` to get past the CORS errors.

```
let headers = {
    'Authorization': 'a',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

axios.get("v1/index-items", { headers: headers })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be in two things: wrong request URL, or CORS problems. In the second case, you need to configure CORS on your backend. Try to look at the headers on the response, are all needed headers there? Try to look in the developer console, there should be CORS error.

Comment: access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: response headers do have these headers in them, but i still have Cors problem and therefore i used proxy to fix it, but still i think we still have problem with Cors, so is there a possibilty that Cors error keeps showing up even after it's fixed in backend?